# How do I schedule rails mailers to send on specific days (heroku)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I'm just needing a bit of advice here.

I have an app that I deployed to heroku, and I have mailers set up so when things like 'record is added' mailers run and send email to users.

One type of mailer I'd like to create is one that goes out on a specific day.

For example, I might say, send mailer on November 3rd at 6:00 am.

How would I go about scheduling that? I mean I can't really use .deliver_later because I realize when the dyno goes to sleep the job will no longer be queued (at least that's how I understand it)

SO I supposed I need to use something like Redis, or Sidekiq, or perhaps Heroku Scheduler? Any advice on this subject would be extremely helpful. I've read a few SO posts about this, but I'm still lost.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using Sidekiq.

Sidekiq allows you to schedule the time when a job will be executed. You use `perform_in(interval_in_seconds, *args)` or `perform_at(timestamp, *args)` rather than the standard `perform_async(*args)`:

```
MyWorker.perform_in(3.hours, 'mike', 1)
MyWorker.perform_at(3.hours.from_now, 'mike', 1)
```

This is useful for example if you want to send the user an email 3 hours after they sign up. Jobs which are scheduled in the past are enqueued for immediate execution.

In your case, you can achieve it using `perform_at(timestamp, *args)` have a look at code -

```
time_stemp = DateTime.parse("09/11/2020 06:00 AM")
SendMailToUserWorker.perform_at(time_stemp, args)
```

More information here -
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this is helpful. But I'm quite lost on where these workers go and how they interact with my controllers. I've tried going through the sidekiq documentation and videos and I'm just not getting it.

Comment: @WesCreations - This worker makes a queue that will execute at specific time. Have a look at sidekiq wiki and you'll get idea for the same. Each sidekiq job have single id, You can anytime pull a specific job by job-id if you wanted to unschedule it.

Comment: Finally got around to getting this working. Thank you so much, it definitely did the trick. However, I had to change the format of the date slightly:     time_stamp = DateTime.parse("21st Aug 2020 07:25:00 PM")

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Heroku. In my case, I use `sidekiq` and `sidekiq-cron` to do some cron job